# What is the name of parameter for styling background color of context menu in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, context-menu, styles

I am looking for parameter which would let me change the background color of context menu in Google Chrome.

[image]

I've visited this site [Theme Tutorial - gsugsa](https://sites.google.com/site/gsugsa/google-apps/google-chrome/how-to-create-a-theme#TOC-Step-6:-Change-the-colors) but I couldn't find there any proper parameter for that (picture below).

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change the context menu color of chrome by any properties itself. That is provided by the operating system. BTW windows 10 has a built in dark mode, which if you enable then context menus will be also black.